# System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache - is locking necessary

Tags: .net, caching

Do we still need to implement locking when working with the `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` e.g. calling `Contains(key);` or is it already thread safe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "Thread Safety" section in the MSDN Library article about a class documents this:

> Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

This is quite normal for .NET classes, the documentation is boilerplate and in a few selected cases uninformative.  That was the case for MemoryCache as well until the documentation got updated.  The Connect feedback article linked by Davide is helpful to clear this up:

> System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache is threadsafe. Multiple concurrent
>   threads can read and write a MemoryCache instance. Internally
>   thread-safety is automatically handled to ensure the cache is updated
>   in a consistent manner.
>
> What this might be referring to is that data stored within the cache
>   may itself not be threadsafe. For example if a List is placed in
>   the cache, and two separate threads both get a reference to the cached
>   List, the two threads will end up stepping on each other if they
>   both attempt to update the list simultaneously.

Comment: MemoryCache class IS thread safe. See the new msdn documentation.

Answer (score 7):

According to the new documentation the MemoryCache class IS thread safe.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx)

[Microsoft connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/564840/the-memorycache-instance-returned-by-memorycache-default-should-be-thread-safe)